# jqGrid. 2 column table. (several rows)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I'm scratching my head trying to accomplish this, maybe some of you have been here before.

I'm using jqgrid in order to give the whole page a similar look, and what I need is pretty simple, just show the data, not sorting etc.
I need to display a 2 column table. Here's some rough example.

```
Name:             Dan
Last Name:        McMillan
Address:          47 st.
Number:           555-55555
Married:          No
```

And so on for a few more rows.... Left column is pretty much always the same, static info. And the right column (all the data itself) is held in a C# variable.

Is there a way to set my left column as the `Headers` of jqgrid? using the values vertically rather than in it's usual way. And how can I then attach the right column to it?

Comment: Why do you need to use jQgrid when you want to show your data in a tabular format..

Comment: trying to make it look as a whole. There'll be more "non-tabular" tables on the page. you suggest to "style" it manually to make it look like the rest of the page?

Comment: It is better to apply styles rather than using jQgrid for tabular data